# Where to download and install clickshare luncher for ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, downloads

where can l find clickshare .deb and how can l install it ?
This link gives the instructions but no down-loadable file https://www.manualslib.com/manual/887612/Barco-Clickshare.html?page=50

Comment: You have to contact them.

Comment: sorry, contact whom ?

Comment: The people who maintain that .deb, it is not an Ubuntu package so yo uhave to contact them directly "https://www.manualslib.com"

Answer (score 3):

There is [no official Linux support for ClickShare anymore](https://www.barco.com/en/Support/clickshare%20csc-1/knowledge-base/KB1191):

> UPDATE : Support for the Linux client has ended as it requires an enormous effort to support all the Linux distributions and their quick updates, while the usage rate of the Linux client was/is very limited.

However, as [described on page 49](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/887612/Barco-Clickshare.html?page=49#manual) of your manual, the software should be available through the web GUI. Depending on the configuration of your device, you might need to ask your local administrator for the file if you don't get/have access to the web GUI.